# Doubt concerning reporting a past event in present

Tags: grammar, tenses

Consider this portion from an article written in November 2019:

> Vertex Pharmaceuticals Incorporated (Nasdaq: VRTX) today confirms that NHS Wales has accepted an offer for all currently licensed Vertex cystic fibrosis (CF).
>
> This means that once the contract is finalized, patients with CF in Wales ages 2 years and older who have two copies of the F508del mutation in the cystic fibrosis transmembrane conductance regulator (CFTR) gene can access ORKAMBI® (lumacaftor/ivacaftor).
>
> The agreement also offers expanded access to KALYDECO® (ivacaftor) to include those patients ages 12 months and older who have one of the nine licensed gating mutations.

If I want to mention the same in a report in July 2020, can I make the following changes:

> In November 2019, NHS Wales **accepted** an offer for all currently licensed Vertex cystic fibrosis (CF).
>
> This **meant** that once the contract is finalized, patients with CF in Wales **aged** 2 years and older who **have had** two copies of the F508del mutation in the cystic fibrosis transmembrane conductance regulator (CFTR) gene could access ORKAMBI® (lumacaftor/ivacaftor).
>
> The agreement also **offered** expanded access to KALYDECO® (ivacaftor) to include those patients **aged** 12 months and older who **have had** one of the nine licensed gating mutations.

Can I get some insights on which of these would be a better alternative, when we are apprehensive about whether the deal mentioned above has been finalized or not?

Comment: The word _age_ in this context is not a verb, so it doesn't need putting into the past tense. But it can be used here in the past participle form. In fact, all of the following are possible: _patients ages 2 years and older,   patients age 2 years and older, patients aged 2 years and older_.

Comment: @Shoe I have come across many instances where "patients aged 2 years and older" were used, but I was doubtful of using the same in this case. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You change the tense of the verbs describing the actions into past tense. But you shouldn't use past tense for the verbs that describe other states. For instance, when referring to the patients affected by it, use the present tense because it continues now (unless the changes only affect patients who were in that state at in the past).

So it should be:

> In November 2019, NHS Wales accepted an offer for all currently licensed Vertex cystic fibrosis (CF).
>
> This meant that once the contract **was** finalized, patients with CF in Wales **ages** 2 years and older who **have** two copies of the F508del mutation in the cystic fibrosis transmembrane conductance regulator (CFTR) gene could access ORKAMBI® (lumacaftor/ivacaftor).
>
> The agreement also offered expanded access to KALYDECO® (ivacaftor) to include those patients **ages** 12 months and older who **have** one of the nine licensed gating mutations.